# MySQL Join on 3 Tables

Tags: mysql, database, join

i have a problem and at that point no clue or starting point how to fix:

I have three Tables with the following fields (i have limited to the important fields):

```
table1    table2        table3
idsp        idsp          did
customer    did
```

What i need is most fields of table1 and table3, table1 is combined to table2 through field idsp and
table2 with table3 on field did.

As i told, i have no starting point... Anyone help?

Thanks,
Sascha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select t1.*, t3.* from 
table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2
  on t1.idsp = t2.idsp
inner join table3 t3
  on t2.did = t3.did
```

Just carry on using joins one after the other.

Comment: @D.N. - you said it :) Thanks a lot Sachin!

Comment: @D.N., @codeworxx - Thanks to you too guys. Glad could help on this ;)